# Using three finger swipe

Tags: multi-touch, trackpad

I liked having a three finger swipe up to spread all open windows and having a three finger swipe down minimize all windows. Is there a way I can implement this in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19467783.aspx) some solution, it works for me (Ubuntu 12.04) with 4 finger drag but you can customize it. Although there are some bugs with the 3 finger drag because ubuntu has some default gestures written in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything directly, but that would definitely be something to file as a feature request with either the [Canonical Multitouch](https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch) group or with the [Unity](https://launchpad.net/unity) group.

[Here are the current supported multitouch actions for Unity.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/#Supported_Gestures)

Comment: As much as I appreciate the help, unfortunately that does not really answer the question :(. There has got to be a better way!

Comment: Perhaps some third party tool the enables keymapping to fnger swipes? On my computer super+w spreads all windows

Comment: Here might be something, though it looks like you have to configure it manually. http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=43097
I would still recommend filing a feature request with the Unity or Multitouch group.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I got the three finger gesture to work was writing a script myself. See this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117981).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.