# My new laptop is powerful, How can i use all its power for ubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, performance, multi-touch, touchscreen

I've recently changed my laptop to a much powerful one and i'm wondering how can i tweak ubuntu to use all the hardware power to speed up system.

My Previous laptop was a [i3 Sony Vaio](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vaio-e-series/vpceb4j0e), And my current laptop is a [i7 Toshoba with 16 GB of ram](http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/S50/S55T-A5237).

Specs are:

- Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ Processor
- 16GB DDR3L 1600MHz memory
- 1.0TB (5400 RPM, Serial ATA)
- Mobile Intel® HD Graphics

‌Based on my experience with my old laptop, i expected to gain a huge performance improvement with this much more powerful laptop. Actually ubuntu is fast enough but sometimes it takes time for a window to open up (Like System Settings), So is there anything to improve the performance ? *(I know the obvious advise whould be to change HDD with an SSD one, but at the moment i'm a little short on money...)*

I did this tweaks already:

- I Installed `Preload`
- Changed the value of `Swappiness` to **10**
- Installed `zram-config` (i don't know if it helps or not since my laptop has lots of ram)
- Moved `/tmp` directory to **RAM**

Also there are few things that bother me:

- When i login to ubuntu, screen **turns black** for few seconds and then Desktop is shown
- Function Keys on my laptop are **reversed** but in ubuntu i need to hold down `FN` to access those functions (i.e. `F7` Key should Play/Pause music by default and to access actual `F7` command, `FN` sholud be held down, but in ubuntu it's opposite)
- Touchpad is Multi-Touch but i cant set 3-4 finger gestures even though i installed `touchegg`
- Keyboard is **backlit** and `FN+Z` should turn light **ON/Off**, but it doesn't work under ubuntu

And one thing else, the laptop has **touch screen display**, i don't really use this feature ( i even didn't know about it when i ordered), but is there any package or anything that lets ubuntu use this feature in a more specific way ? (i don't think so, just a long shot ;) )

Thanks

Comment: Did you take the hard drive out of the i3 Sony and put it into the i7 Toshiba? There is a wiki on Multitouch [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch) as well.

Comment: @wilf No, its brand new

Comment: for the keyboard [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/how-to-light-up-back-lit-keyboard) might help - you can use `xset led 3` or [`setleds...`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/setleds.1.html). There is a tutorial [here](http://www.techdrivein.com/2013/03/4-simple-tweaks-to-improve-unity-performance-ubuntu.html) for speeding things up by removing some of the flashy effects Unity has, and there is a wiki [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) for Touchscreens.

Answer (score 1):

"I know the obvious advise whould be to change HDD with an SSD one ...", wait until you can afford a SSD. All other optimizations will give you only measurable, but not sensible, perfomance boosts (apart from `preload` maybe). Your machine has more than enough power to work fluidly with ubuntu.

You should *think the other way around*, **how to use this processing power reasonable?** Lastly, there has to be a reason to buy a laptop with so much processing power.

PS:

- The reason why your screen turns black after login for a few seconds, is due the fact that your hdd is preloading something.
- Because you haven't posted your `lsusb` output, i assume that your touchpad is from synaptics. Do you have installed `gsynaptics` and the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`?

Comment: Actually I'm Android Developer, I changed my laptop because i needed to have Eclipse+NetBeans+GenyMotion+Chromioum opened at the same time and it got so slow sometimes, right now I've configured my IDEs to use much more ram at start up. And no, I didnt installed those packages, would you please explain more about them ?

Comment: i'm sure my touchpad is from Synaptic, it works OK, two finger scrolling is working, i've installed `touchegg` and `ginn` but none of them worked for me (i can't use 3-finger or 4-finger gestures), as i understand its a bug that affects ubuntu 12.10 and above

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160524/using-three-finger-swipe) could help you to use multi touch gestures. 

PS: If you want a short description about a package use the onboard tools: f.e. `aptitude show gsynaptics`.

Comment: I've installed `gpointing-device-setting` but didn't help on gestures, that's not a big deal although, two fingers is enough for now. Any idea on how to reverse `F-Keys` behavior ?